# Difference between shown issues and value in UI

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web, sonarqube-5.4

We've got an strange issue. For doing branch reintegration we first analysed the base branch and then the branch to reintegrate on the same project key but different versions.

After having both results we have a strange result. The dashboard shows a different number of new issues than the issue overview for the given project.

[image: Dashboard]

When you click e.g. on the 9 new blocker issues you get this number of new issues:

[image: Issue overview]

Is there any reason for the difference of given issues? Is this a fault in sonarqube or is there a reason for this result.

We are using Sonarqube 5.4 on a JAVA project.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dashboard values are calculated at analysis time. So when your analysis completed, there were 9 blocker issues. The numbers in the Issues page are calculated *on the fly*, so this means that someone

- Resolved issues (Won't Fix or False Positive)
- Downgraded issues

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this project key nobody else is working. When I analyze all issues I get the following result: all issues are "unresolved" except of 790 fixed issues. These were about 9 criticals and ~780 majors. The ruleset war not edited either. Any other ideas?

Comment: cleaning the results and doing the analysis again solved the issue for us.<br> Made new analysis of the trunk and later of the branch to reintegrate in the trunk. The result seemed valid. Maybe the reason was in removed rules or resolved rules.